# Hybrid app with native iOS features

Tags: xcode, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to build a hybrid app with some native features like geotagging, notifications and offline storage. So far in my research I got the feeling that I will need xCode to access the native features on iOS.
Is there a way that I can skip that step? I have found that Cordova API, supports native features with JavaScript, but also I have found some contradicting statements witch suggest that I also need to also use xCode.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build an iOS-App you'll need Xcode's command line tools to build, run and deploy your App. So you can't skip this step.

Comment: cordova will only control these for you

Answer (score 0):

The [Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) tooling lets you develop your app without the need for Xcode (or Android Studio). You use a companion app from App Store to develop locally, then an online Build Service to create a stand-alone package. The wrapper provides access to many native APIs, including all Cordova core plugins.

(Disclaimer: I work for AppGyver.)